Extend Grammars and add new function
in laravel i need to extend the postgresql grammar to add a functionality, to create a conditional unique index
in debugging I was only able to reach the uniqueSoftDelete milestone, it does not enter the extended function compileUniqueSoftDelete
PostgresGrammar  extended
<?php

namespace App\Database\Schema\Grammars;

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\PostgresGrammar as BasePostgresGrammar;
use Illuminate\Support\Fluent;

class PostgresGrammar extends BasePostgresGrammar
{
    /**
     * Compile a unique key command.
     *
     * @param Blueprint $blueprint
     * @param Fluent $command
     * @return string
     */
    public function compileUniqueSoftDelete(Blueprint $blueprint, Fluent $command): string
    {
        // Extrai as colunas e o nome do índice
        $columns = $this->columnize($command->columns);
        $indexName = $this->wrap($command->indexName);

        // Retorna o SQL que cria o índice único condicional
        return "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX {$indexName} ON {$this->wrapTable($blueprint)} ({$columns}) WHERE deleted_at IS NULL";
    }

}


Provider
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Database\Schema\Grammars\PostgresGrammar;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\PostgresBuilder;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class PostgresSchemaGrammarServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        // Define a macro uniqueSoftDelete no Blueprint
        Blueprint::macro('uniqueSoftDelete', function ($columns, $name = null) {
            // Garante que as colunas sejam um array
            if (is_string($columns)) {
                $columns = [$columns];
            }

            // Cria o nome do índice se não foi passado
            $indexName = empty($name) ? $this->createIndexName('unique_soft_delete', $columns) : $name;

            // Adiciona o comando ao fluxo de migration
            return $this->addCommand('uniqueSoftDelete', compact('indexName', 'columns'));
        });
    }

    public function boot(): void
    {
        // Substitui o Grammar padrão pelo customizado
        // Use a resolução do schema para substituir o grammar da conexão com PostgreSQL
        $this->app->resolving('db.schema', function ($connection) {
            if ($connection instanceof PostgresBuilder) {
                // Substitua o grammar da conexão por nosso customizado
                $connection->getConnection()->setSchemaGrammar(new PostgresGrammar());
            }
        });
    }
}

Migration
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('folha.testes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('tenant_id')->unsigned()->nullable(false)->comment('Empresa')->constrained('geral.tenants')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('restrict');
            $table->string('cpf')->nullable(false)->comment('CPF');

            //$table->unique(['cpf']);
            $table->uniqueSoftDelete(['cpf'])->comment('CPF Único');

            $table->softDeletes()->comment('Excluído Logicamente');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent()->comment('Criado');
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent()->comment('Alterado');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('geral.testes');
    }
};


I need to create a new command for laravel migration to enter the command flow
I need to extend laravel migration to create a new command, so that I can use it when creating tables, just like the foreignId command generates a line "alter table "folha"."testes" add constraint "folha_testes_sistema_id_foreign" foreign key ("sistema_id") references "geral"."sistemas" ("id") on delete restrict on update cascade" I need to add a new command compileUniqueSoftDelete
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/2024_10_14_163516_create_testes_table.php --pretend

I'm unsure exactly what your question is?

I need to extend laravel migration to create a new command, so that I can use it when creating tables, just like the foreignId command generates a line "alter table "folha"."testes" add constraint "folha_testes_sistema_id_foreign" foreign key ("sistema_id") references "geral"."sistemas" ("id") on delete restrict on update cascade" I need to add a new command compileUniqueSoftDelete
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/2024_10_14_163516_create_testes_table.php --pretend
